# pySide/ pyQt - Marker bar?

Tags: qt, pyside

What would be the easiest way to create a marker bar in PySide/ PyQt, similar to

[image: this]
<sub>(source: [sideofsoftware.com](http://www.sideofsoftware.com/marker_bar_screen_shot_netbeans.jpg))</sub>
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`QScrollBar`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qscrollbar.html) class.  You can subclass it and override the [`paintEvent`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#paintEvent) method to do custom painting.  Any class that inherits from `QAbstractScrollArea` (e.g. `QScrollArea`, `QTextEdit`, etc.) has two methods to set the scrollbar for the vertical or horizontal scrollbar (e.g. `setVerticalScrollbar()`).  So create your own scrollbar class and then use those methods to apply it to the widgets that can use it.

Comment: Thanks for this. I found a solution for a marker bar in C# which involves creating a list box with 1-pixel high lines, would something like that work in Qt?

Comment: Well, you can make anything work, but that seems kind of hacky.  Using the scroll bar seems to make the most sense since the types of things that would need a marker bar already have a scroll bar.